# r create bar plot with two y variables

Tags: r, bar-chart

I would like to create a barplot in r that takes two y variables and displays them side by side, for one x variable.
Below is the output of a put function of the data that I am trying to plot

```
structure(list(SpindleID = structure(1:20, .Label = c("3001", 
"3002", "3003", "3004", "3005", "3006", "3007", "3008", "3009", 
"3010", "3501", "3502", "3503", "3504", "3505", "3506", "3507", 
"3508", "3509", "3510"), class = "factor"), lowtor = c(39, 83, 
70, 123, 31, 36, 128, 213, 134, 27, 223, 197, 286, 65, 744, 664, 
465, 60, 140, 115), hitor = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 5, 
8, 1, 0, 155, 96, 28, 27, 12, 16)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -20L))
```

The x variable is SpindleID and the two y variables are lower and hitor.

Thanks

Comment: Actually just `barplot(t(df[-1]), beside=TRUE)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make a longer format dataframe using `pivot_longer` to make it easy to show your two variables as bars side by side with `ggplot` like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -SpindleID) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = SpindleID, y = value, fill = name)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>